# iOS 7 Like Page Transitions for jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know of transitions for jQuery Mobile that look like the native iOS 7 slide transitions (and have the capability of being swiped back)?

The standard "slide" transition is close, but does not have the swipe back feature.

The swipe feature that I am looking for is the user swiping and the page moving with their finger, not simply swipe left and then the page transitions in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a slider with some bounceback like in iOS? CSS has you covered ;) `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for page transitions, not just the overflow scrolling. Any ideas?